# how to check if function(s) have been executed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, comparison

I am new to javascript and i am facing a situation here

```
if (function1() && function2() == true){
   //do something here

 }
   else{

   //do something else

}
```

how do i ensure that function1() and function2() are executed and have true value ?

Comment: You can drop the `== true` since they both return booleans.

Comment: If this condition `if (function1() && function2() ){` is true, it means that these functions was executed and returned true.

Comment: just be aware of that if the first function doesn't return true or the second won't be executed.

Comment: Should `function2()` be called regardless of `function1()`'s return value or only when it returns `true`?

Comment: `function1()` is the return value of `function1` when it is invoked, so is `function2` when invoked like `function2()`, what is the problem..?

Answer (score 4):

What you have done is correct. Since you using `&&` they both execute and when they both return true then only it enters the `if`.

As a side note, your code can be shorten to

```
if (function1() && function2()){
```

Comment: @leo It will only work if those functions are not AJAX, since you didn't mention what are those functions

Comment: @RamonMarques OP never mentioned that they have ajax calls.